# Three.js always rotate about world center

Tags: three.js

I'm currently following [a tutorial](https://manu.ninja/webgl-3d-model-viewer-using-three-js/) on how to get a 3d model view in three.js
But I notice that whenever I pan the camera (right-click and drag), the center of rotation changes.
Is it possible to make the axis of rotation stay in the world center/object center?
Many thanks!

Comment: It's not possible to do that with `OrbitControls`. You need a custom control class for this.

Comment: how would I go about implementing it? Can I just slightly modify OrbitControls?